# Array Assign in VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an Excel sheet which has a data range from A5 to AU3950. I want to copy the data into an array which has the dimensions `MyArray(3950, 68)`. I would like to copy each row (A5:AU5) into MyArray(ArrayRow, 28 to 67).

```
Sub Import(ByRef MyArray, Sheet)
    Dim Colx, Rowx, ArrayRow, ArrayCol
    Dim Wsheet
    Dim TempArray()
    Set WSheet = MyWorkBook.Sheets(Sheet)
    WSheet.Activate
    LastRow = WSheet.Cells(WSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).Row
    ReDim MyArray(LastRow-4, 68)
    ArrayRow = 0
    For Rowx = 5 To LastRow
        ArrayCol = 28
        TempArray = WSheet.Range(WSheet.Cells(Rowx, 7), WSheet.Cells(Rowx, 46)).Value
        MyArray(ArrayRow, ArrayCol) = TempArray
        ArrayRow = ArrayRow + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want the rows as Excel ranges in the array? Then you don't need a 2-dimensional array. Or do you want the values in the fields of the array? Then what do you want with the rows? What do you want to do with the data in the end?

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I just want to assign the sheets data into 2d array so i can easily access after that. I have to check the each row & column data later part of the program.

Comment: Is the data range always the same (3950x68)? Or do you want the array sized dynamically depending on how many rows/columns actually hold data?

Comment: I do it dynamically according to last row in the sheet with Redim but column width is fixed.

Comment: @Developer_World I guess you need just `MyArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Value`

Comment: I think it will take all data in current region. How can I find by each cell.